# How to implement a doubly linked list that accommodates integers and void pointers?

Tags: c++, linked-list, void-pointers

I am trying to implement my own version of common data structures to improve my coding. I have an assignment that requires a doubly linked list that can hold `int` and void pointers, `void * data`. My struct has two member types, one for `int` and one for `void*`.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    void* pntData;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};
class LL {
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
public:
    LL();
    void insert_front(int data);
    void insert_front(void* data);//overloaded for void pointer data types
    void printLL();//removed unrelated methods
};
```

Here is my Node struct and doubly linked list class. I have been able to write all the methods that handle `int`. My confusion lies in taking a void pointer as a parameter and adding it to the same linked list with the `int` values.

I understand that a void pointer is a pointer that can point to any kind of data, but I am confused as to how I am supposed to take a void pointer as a parameter and add it to the same linked list that I initialized with this constructor:

```
LL::LL() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}
```

Here are my append functions, where I had the idea of overloading so that if the parameter was a pointer, the data would be added as a `void* pntData` in my class variable. If the parameter was an int, the data would be added as an `int` in my class variable.

```
void LL::insert_front(int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = temp;
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        temp->data = data;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        temp->next = head;
        temp->data = data;
        head->previous = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    size++;
}

void LL::insert_front(void* data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = temp;
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        temp->pntData = data;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        temp->next = head;
        temp->pntData = data;
        head->previous = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    size++;
}
```

The issue may lay in my `printLL()` function, which might needed to have a if/else to determine if an `int` needs to be printed or a `void* pntData` needs to be printed.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: The "right direction" for you would be a C++ book that covers modern C++; specifically the chapter on how to use the `std::variant` template, which accomplishes exactly what you're asking about. It'll make your program much simpler, like needing only one `insert_front`(), instead of painful code duplication. After reading it, and some practice, you should be able to complete this "online assignment". Good luck!

Comment: I think it might be more educational to template your linked list on the value type, i.e. write a generic `LinkedList<T>` containing a `Node<T>` class.  Then, you can use linked lists holding integers, and (separately) void pointers.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good exercise. Storing a `void*` pointer in a container is pointless if you don't store information about the type to which the pointer is pointing as well, but that is a rather difficult task and you would in practice just use `std::variant` or (seldom) `std::any` as element type of a type-generic container instead.

Comment: What do you expect `printLL()` to print if the element is a `void*`? The address stored in the pointer or the thing that the pointer is pointing to? Do you want the list to accept a null pointer as valid value to store for `void*`?

Comment: While I agree with you this is the assignment I have to follow.  So I can't store the void pointer in the Node struct without also storing the type along with it?

Comment: @walnut I am expecting to print the thing the pointer is pointing to, the value. Yes I want the list to store the value that we won't know until runtime

Comment: @Suede Then what you want to do is impossible with the given definition of `Node`/`LL`, because you cannot know what type the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: So I would have to change my structure and class?

Comment: Could I add a parameter that describes the type (double, int, string) in the class so that it could be casted within the method?

Comment: @Suede See my answer.

Comment: His approach is described in "Hypermodern C++", appendx 4 "Escaping the type system." ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments you want `printLL()` to print the object that the `void*` pointer is pointing to.

That is impossible. The `void*` pointer has no information about the type that it is pointing to, so you cannot dereference the pointer.

If you want to do this, then you need to store an additional pointer to a handler function in `Node`, that `printLL()` will call for each `Node` to print its `void*`. Then you need to make the `insert_*` functions templates on the pointer type, so that you can figure out the correct function pointer to store for the provided type, i.e.:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    void* pntData;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
    void(*print)(void*) = nullptr; // Initialize with null pointer to indicate that no `void*` is stored.
};

//...

template<typename T>
void LL::insert_front(T* data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    //...
    temp->print = [](void* ptr){
        if(ptr != nullptr)
            std::cout << *static_cast<T*>(ptr);
        else
            // What to do if we stored a null pointer for `void*`
    };
    //...
}

//...

void LL::printLL() {
    //...
    if(node->print != nullptr)
        node->print(node->pntData);
    //...
}
```

I have a feeling that this is not what the exercise intends you to do, but as I said in the comments, it doesn't make sense to me in the first place.

Comment: The list should accommodate integers and pointers. You may add other types as you need them. Include member functions for the following: 
**void insert_front(int data );**
**void insert_front(void *data );** 
**void insert_rear(int data );** 
**void insert_rear(void *data );** 
**int remove_front_i( );** 
**void * remove_front_p( );** 
**int remove_rear_i( );** 
**void * remove_rear_p( );** 
**int empty( );**  
Use dynamic memory. Use the "new" instruction to allocate memory when inserting and the delete instruction to return the memory when removing.

Comment: @Suede And what is the specification for `printLL`?

Comment: That was the instruction, your answer looks very helpful. I am going to return shortly after dinner. Thank you so much for your help, void pointers are confusing for me as I come Java.

Comment: there isn't one that is for me to test my implementation.

Comment: @Suede You almost never need `void*` in C++. It is much more common in C. That is why the exercise is so confusing. It is not how C++ is normally written. If you don't need the `printLL` and if the list is supposed to only ever work with the *same* pointer type given to it, then you don't need what I wrote in my answer. It is the `printLL` function (or any other function that requires the type) that makes it difficult to implement. If you don't need this function, then you can just store an additional `bool` that indicates whether you are storing an `int` or `void*`.

Comment: @Suede In C++ if the contents can be changed, but is always the same in a given list, make the list a class template. If the list can contain different objects, but all part of a family, that's inheritance in action. If you must be able to store anything, you probably have a design flaw, but in the rare case that it isn't you may have a case for `void *` and should look into `std::variant` or `std::any` before you decide on `void *`.

Comment: @walnut So if I get ride of `printLL()`, then will the LL be able to hold both `int` and void pointers as it already is? I just created printLL to ensure my other methods were working. I simply need a doubly linked list that can hold both `int` and void pointers. I do not need to print.

Comment: @Suede Yes, then you can use it the way you did, just add a `bool` to remember whether you saved an `int` or a `void*`. As explained by user4581301 this isn't how C++ is usually written though. It is more akin to C.

Comment: Okay. I have a professor that has been teaching for 25 years and is teaching me data structures and algorithms. Seemingly without notice, he switched between C and C++ while teaching us code on a white board. So that probably adds to my confusion.

Comment: @walnut, so, essentially I need to add a bool to my class to be used when inserting into the LL? True when `int` and false when `void *`? How can I display the contents of the LL?

Comment: @Suede This is sadly done often. Teaching C++ as an extension of C made sense at some point, but modern C++'s idiomatic style is very different from C and it would be much better if either *only* C was taught or actual modern C++ was taught from the beginning, since mixing the two makes everything unnecessarily complicated as you are seeing here yourself. (Although it is meant for the teacher, not the student, there is for example [this good CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) about this issue.)

Comment: @Suede You cannot display the contents from inside the queue. That is the (pointless) restriction of using `void*`. Only the code using the queue knows what type the elements are that it stored in the queue and only that user code can cast the `void*` pointer back to the original type and use the value it points to. As I said, unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207542/discussion-between-suede-and-walnut).